# How to set index values in a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame and need to change the level 0 index *values*.  The current DataFrame has a MultiIndex called `(test, time)`.

How do I set the string "Test 4" (in the top level of the index) to be some other string?

For extra points, many of my DataFrames will have more than one value in the `test` level of the index.  Can I use a list of names to rename more than one at a time?

Thank you for any help.

[image]

(edited:) My data is:

```
test      time     force  displacement  minutes  event
'Test 4'  0.0000   .1202   0            0.00000  False
'Test 4'  0.0012   .0901   0            0.00002  False
'Test 4'  0.0018   .0901   0            0.00003  False
'Test 4'  0.0030   .0901   0            0.00004  False
'Test 4'  0.0042   .0901   0            0.00005  False
'Test 5'  0.0000   .1203   0            0.00000  False
'Test 5'  0.0012   .0901   0            0.00002  False
```

with a multi index set to `['test', 'time']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary to `rename` to rename specific values in any index.

```
df.rename(index={'Test4':'something else'})
```

Comment: Also appears to work with multiindex, i.e. `df.rename(columns={'My value',:'My new value'}, inplace=True)` (the latter is needed when you don't want to bother with a new df).

Answer (score 3):

First off, don't post a pic without the data?

Second of all:

```
df.index.set_levels(['Test4'], level=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Sorry about the image - I tried a markdown table but it didn't seem to render so didn't know the best way to show the data in a well-laid-out way.  If there's a question somewhere that has used decent markup, please point me to it so I can look at the markup and learn.  Thanks

Comment: @blokeley best way is to provide the code that generates the example.  Second best way is to paste csv to the question.  Your example is small, that could have been done easily.  Without it, I give you a sorry answer without a verified demonstration.

Comment: This doesn't really work well if there is more than one value in the `test` index.

Comment: Hence why it's important to post the data.  You still can.  I'm not going to take the time to create it for you.  It's sitting right there in front of you.  All you have to do is copy and paste it to your post.  With it, I can show you more completely what to do.

Comment: It works fine if there is more than one value in the `test` index - simple add to the list of new names.